# Error al guardar datos json en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

Estoy intentando almacenar estos datos **JSON**:

```
{
    "ticker": {
        "base": "ETH",
        "target": "USD",
        "price": "689.18009232",
        "volume": "234831.85174911",
        "change": "1.48138601"
    },
    "timestamp": 1525308422,
    "success": true,
    "error": ""
}
```

En mi *Base de Datos* y al ejecutar el **PHP** me salen estos errores:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ticker in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23
>
> Notice: Undefined index: ticker in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23 PHP Notice:
>   Undefined index: ticker in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23
>
> Notice: Undefined index: ticker in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23 PHP
>   Warning:  Illegal string offset 'ticker' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'ticker' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23 PHP Notice:
>   Uninitialized string offset: 0 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23
>
> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23 PHP
>   Warning:  Illegal string offset 'base' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'base' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23 PHP Notice:
>   Uninitialized string offset: 0 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23
>
> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23 PHP
>   Warning:  Illegal string offset 'ticker' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'ticker' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23 PHP Notice:
>   Uninitialized string offset: 0 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23
>
> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23 PHP
>   Warning:  Illegal string offset 'volume' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'volume' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23 PHP Notice:
>   Uninitialized string offset: 0 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23
>
> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\crypto4allfinal\jsonToMySQL.php on line 23

A continuación dejo el código **PHP**:

```
<?php

/*$bucle=true;
do {*/

    $json = file_get_contents('datosCriptomonedas.json');
    $datosclientes = json_decode($json, true);

    $server = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $bd = "crypto4all";

    //Creamos la conexión
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass,$bd) 
    or die("Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la conexion de la base de datos");

    //var_dump($cliente);

    foreach ($datosclientes as $cliente) {

        mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO criptomoneda (nombre,volumen) 
        VALUES ('".$cliente['ticker']['base']."',".$cliente['ticker']['volume'].")");
    }   

    mysqli_close($conexion);
/*
    sleep(60);//1 minuto
} while ($bucle);*/

?>
```

**El resultado de la variable es el siguiente:**

```
Array
(
    [ticker] => Array
        (
            [base] => ETH
            [target] => USD
            [price] => 689.18009232
            [volume] => 234831.85174911
            [change] => 1.48138601
        )

    [timestamp] => 1525308422
    [success] => 1
    [error] => 
)
```

Comment: No veo el código

Comment: @RaulA. He quitado las etiquetas de php ya.

Comment: Hola, podrías hacer `print_r($datosclientes)` para ver como se están guardando los datos en esa variable.

Comment: El problema es que estás iterando sobre el mapa, los índices en tu foreach van a ser ticker, timestamp, success, error. Por eso te sale el error de índice inexistente

Comment: @KacosPro Exacto, por eso accedo de esta manera: ".$cliente['ticker']['base']."

Comment: Por eso, debes acceder directamente a $datosclientes y no utilizar el foreach. Así: `$datosclientes['ticker']['base']`

Comment: @KacosPro. cierto, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este bucle tu estás iterando sobre los índices de `$datoscliente`

```
foreach ($datosclientes as $cliente) {

    mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO criptomoneda (nombre,volumen) 
    VALUES ('".$cliente['ticker']['base']."',".$cliente['ticker']['volume'].")");
}
```

Lo que debes hacer es acceder directamente al arreglo original y no utilizar el `foreach`

```
mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO criptomoneda (nombre,volumen) 
VALUES ('".$datoscliente['ticker']['base']."',".$datoscliente['ticker']['volume'].")");
```

Por cierto estás expuesto a un grave problema de seguridad llamado [Inyección SQL](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php), puedes ver aquí como evitarla: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php)